# Scrape multiple RSS links in R

Tags: r, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape multiple RSS links in R (those are +800 news articles)

I was able to scrape individual URLs by:

```
    cnn_url <- "http://rss.cnn.com/~r/rss/cnn_travel/~3/-GFuCIsYZgQ/index.html"
    cnn_html <- read_html(cnn_url)
    cnn_html

    cnn_nodes <- cnn_html %>% html_elements(".Article__body")
    #look for texts
    cnn_texts <- cnn_html %>% 
    html_elements(".Article__body") %>% 
    html_text()

    cnn_texts[1]
```

But I am trying to scrape +800 articles (the main text of news stories) in R, and I can't run the codes above for each URL because I have more than +800 links. So I used the codes:

```
    cnn_data <- news_data %>% 
    filter(media_name  == "CNN")
    head(cnn_data$url)
    head(cnn_data)

    urls <- cnn_data[,4] #column with url
    url_xml <- try(apply(urls, 1, read_html)) 

    textScraper <- function(x) {
    html_text(html_nodes (x, ".Article__body") %>% 
              html_nodes("p")) %>%
    paste(collapse = '')}

    cnn_text <- lapply(url_xml, textScraper)
    cnn_text[1]

    cnn_data$full_article <- cnn_text
    head(cnn_data$full_article)
```

But when I ran the line:

```
    url_xml <- try(apply(urls, 1, read_html))
```

I got an error message that says: Error in open.connection(x, "rb") : HTTP error 404.

I assume this may be because the URLs are linked to RSS; is there any way I can scrape those news stories by using the URLs that I have?

FYI: data file consists of rows that have links like this--

```
http://rss.cnn.com/~r/rss/cnn_travel/~3/-GFuCIsYZgQ/index.html
http://rss.cnn.com/~r/rss/cnn_latest/~3/WvpC9ZKjJXo/index.html
http://rss.cnn.com/~r/rss/cnn_latest/~3/przZf_johNY/index.html
http://rss.cnn.com/~r/rss/cnn_latest/~3/TieFj4roU_M/index.html
http://rss.cnn.com/~r/rss/cnn_latest/~3/iqRZ7f8MhzQ/index.html
http://rss.cnn.com/~r/rss/cnn_latest/~3/Uq46bJROhiI/index.html
http://rss.cnn.com/~r/rss/cnn_latest/~3/6u-D9sna6uY/index.html
http://rss.cnn.com/~r/rss/cnn_latest/~3/JNTXgcM1yY0/index.html
http://rss.cnn.com/~r/rss/cnn_latest/~3/WG8UTHcZvwQ/index.html
http://rss.cnn.com/~r/rss/cnn_latest/~3/6YHMwdj6W7s/index.html
```

Comment: Most likely at least one of those links are not valid thus generating the error.  You likely need to step through each URL individually and use a Try-Catch strategy to handle any errors with the URLS.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! Please correct me if I'm wrong--but that is why I used try(). Even if there is a "problematic" link, there should be no problem in loading the rest of the links if I'm using try(). I also tried safely(), possibly() instead of try(), with and without "silent = TRUE" at the end of the code. But they didn't work.

Comment: Update: A friend of mine told me that the problem here may be each URL link has slightly different html structures, so for the first link, .Article__body worked, but for the second link, it should be .l-container. Is there any way I can gather all those different html tags for the body paragraphs and apply them to my codes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `try()` statement is testing the return from the call to `apply()`, thus if there is one bad link the apply will error and then the try statement takes over. You need to wrap the try around `read_html` and not the apply.
Something like this should work, returning a list of web pages.  Note all of your above links work.

```
library(rvest)

mylist<-lapply(urls, function(url) {
   #be kind and not attack the server
   Sys.sleep(1)
   print(url)  #debug
   url_xml<-try(read_html(url))
})
```

Yes, it possible to code to handle the different pages, but that is potentially a much bigger question to answer.